# How can I embed SCSS in a Pugjs template using jstransformer-scss and pug-cli?

Tags: html, node.js, sass, pug

Using WebStorm's 'File Watchers' feature and pug-cli, I'm creating a pug template which is automatically built into an HTML file when the pug template is modified. For exogenous reasons, I need to embed the CSS within my HTML files so I can use it within a third-party ecommerce platform. Here is my current attempt at embedding the CSS within a PUG template which doesn't work because pug doesn't support 'require':

---

template.pug

```
- var jstscss = require('jstransformer')(require('jstransformer-scss'))
- var scss = `

    @import "../a-file-I-need-imported"
    $bgcolor = #fff;
    body {
        background-color: $bgcolor;
    }

`

script.
    !{jstscss.render(scss)}
```

This would ideally be built into:

---

template.html

```
<script>

    body {
        background-color: #fff; }

    // a-file-I-need-imported's CSS, that was imported. (i.e. Mixins, other variables, etc.)

</script>
```

---

package.json

```
"build:pug": "pug --pretty --basedir ./ --out ./dist/ ./src"
```

---

How can I accomplish this feat while still using pug-cli? (Which is what WebStorm's File Watcher is using along with my package.json's build script.)

Edit: I assume it will be related to re-coding the render function in pug-cli and injecting the jstransformer, but I'm unfamiliar with node, javascript, pug so I'm not sure how I would go about doing that without directly editing the node_module, which would get overridden if I ever update it. Is there anything like a Wordpress Child Theme for node modules? lol.

Comment: I would write a node script that calls `pug.render('your template',locals)` where `locals.jstscss = require('jstransformer')(require('jstransformer-scss'))`

Answer (score 0):

Just call a new script, like `node build.js` and use the pug module since `pug-cli` does not support passing anything beyond JSON objects or files to `locals`

build.js

```
const pug = require('pug')
const jstscss = require('jstransformer')(require('jstransformer-scss'))
let locals = {jstscss};
const html = pug.renderFile('./template.pug',locals);
console.log(html); // instead, output your file using this function.
```

template.pug

```
- var scss = `@import "./import"; $bgcolor : #fff; body {background-color: $bgcolor;}`

style.
    !{jstscss.render(scss).body}
```

import.scss

```
body{
  font-size:12px;
}
```

output in this case

```
<style>body {
  font-size: 12px; }

body {
  background-color: #fff; }
</style>
```

https://repl.it/@CodyGeisler/PugRendersScss

Comment: So I tried doing this but the issue now is that I don't have just one template file, I have endless template files since some of the templates are for things like creating a new website <section>. I've modified your code like so, but there isn't a way to write the compiled code into an actual file in my destination directory? Here is the forked version of your code: https://repl.it/repls/PettyTidyBits

Comment: `const {writeFile} = require('fs')` pretty well, and then if you're in `async/await` land you can `const wireFileAsync = require('utils').promisify(writeFile)` and just `await writeFileAsync(html,'./export')` --- I wrote this off the top of my head so some stuff might be slightly wrong --- I'm not sure you can write files in repl.it, which is why I just showed it in `console.log` ;)